Downsides of performing automatic differentiation in one pass as opposed to splitting the calculation into smaller chunks
In a multidisciplinary optimization problem that I'm working on, AD is used to compute the derivatives of the most computationally-intensive discipline of the model. How much benefit would I get from splitting the component into separate subcomponents? I would still provide the derivatives of the subcomponents using AD as partial derivatives and eventually compute the total derivatives using analytical adjoint formulation.
In addition to that, the derivative I am computing is second order and features an iterative solution.
I'm mostly interested in assessing the potential benefits in terms of performance and improved numerical stability of the derivatives process. Improved modularity, reusability, maintenaince, scalabiltiy that comes with using smaller functions are outside the scope of my question.
I am trying to find mentions of specific benefits that arise from this approach in the literature, but didn't manage to identify anything about advantages of splitting AD computations into smaller ones to provide "simpler" partials to an adjoint process for derivatives.
